# Divide post content into two columns, one fixed

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to get my posts to automatically divide into two columns with one column fixed, one scrolling. Example -

[image]

Similar to [this website](http://www.cosstores.com/gb/Magazine/SS14/Miranda_July/).

So far I've managed to divide the post into two, though it's not behaving how I want it to. I did -

The HTML

```
<td class="entry-content-left">
<div class="entry-image">
<td class="entry-content-right">
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

The CSS

```
.entry-content-left { 
font-size: 18px;
line-height: 26px;
width: 531px; 
float: left; 
color: #444444;
} 
 .entry-content-right { 
font-size: 18px;
line-height: 26px;
width: 531px; 
float: right; 
color: #444444; 
}
.entry-image {
float: left; width: 75%; position: fixed;
```

Here is [my website](http://tinyurl.com/ocpz7a2).

Comment: You're going to want to look into CSS [fixed positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Fixed_positioning).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `position:fixed;` ([more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Fixed_positioning)). I made this quick layout using  divs, (you should not be using tables for this kind of content) that should be the desired layout :

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/D5kMJ/)**

*HTML:*

```
<header></header>
<div class="entry-content-left">
    <div class="entry-image"></div>
    <div class="entry-content-right"></div>
</div>
```

*CSS:*

```
header{
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    top:0;left:0;
    height:100px;
    background:gold;
}
.entry-image{
    position:fixed;
    top:100px;left:5%;
    width:40%;
}
.entry-image img{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
.entry-content-right{
    width:45%;
    margin-left:50%;
    margin-top:120px;
}
```

Comment: That's kinda similar to what I had originally though and it didn't work :-/

Comment: @SocialMonster why didn't it work? The code I provided in my answer works, maybe you have some CSS conflicts that break the layout?

Comment: It just didnt. No CSS conflicting it either. Take a look: http://tinyurl.com/ocpz7a2

Comment: @SocialMonster in your link, there is no `position:fixed;` on the image. `.entry-image` has `position:fixed;`but it is empty.

Comment: Hmm.. I have absolutely no idea what im doing wrong... http://jsfiddle.net/cbU9t/4/

Comment: @SocialMonster well, I just moved the image in the HTML markup so it is inside `.entry-image` witch is positioned corectly.

Comment: It doesn't work though. In the HTML markup I have this http://jsfiddle.net/8jmfy/ yet the image still appears on the right hand side

Comment: @SocialMonster Have you had a look at this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/cbU9t/5/ in this fiddle, the image is on the left, it doesn't scroll and the text is on the right and scrolls. Wasn't this what you needed?

Comment: Yeah, it is. But it doesn't work. When I updated the pages with your code the image still went to the right with the text underneath http://tinyurl.com/ocpz7a2

Comment: @SocialMonster This code works if you put the image inside `.entry-image` if you can't, you can use this code : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/RGDf8/

Comment: @SocialMonster Glad you dound a solutio. please accept/upvote answer if it help.